# Not able to see horizontal page indicator

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I started learning jetpack compose and am currently stuck at the moment where I am not able to see the horizontal page indicator and not able to swipe to the next page too. Only the screen at startDestination is visible.

I have referred this from stevdza-san youtube channel

Here is the first screen.
[image: First screen image]

**Onboard Screen**

```
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun OnBoardScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
){
    val pages = listOf(
        OnBoardingPage.First,
        OnBoardingPage.Second,
        OnBoardingPage.Third
    )
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(10f),
            count = 3,
            state = pagerState,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top
        ) { position ->
            PagerScreen(onBoardingPage = pages[position])
        }
        HorizontalPagerIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                .weight(1f),
            pagerState = pagerState
        )
        FinishButton(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            pagerState = pagerState
        ) {
           // welcomeViewModel.saveOnBoardingState(completed = true)
            navController.popBackStack()
            navController.navigate(Screen.Home.route)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun PagerScreen(onBoardingPage: OnBoardingPage) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.5f)
                .fillMaxHeight(0.7f),
            painter = painterResource(id = onBoardingPage.image),
            contentDescription = "Pager Image"
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            text = onBoardingPage.title,
            fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.h4.fontSize,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 40.dp)
                .padding(top = 20.dp),
            text = onBoardingPage.description,
            fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1.fontSize,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun FinishButton(
    modifier: Modifier,
    pagerState: PagerState,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 40.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        AnimatedVisibility(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            visible = pagerState.currentPage == 2
        ) {
            Button(
                onClick = onClick,
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    contentColor = Color.White
                )
            ) {
                Text(text ="Finish")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview(showBackground = true)
fun FirstOnBoardingScreenPreview() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        PagerScreen(onBoardingPage = OnBoardingPage.First)
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview(showBackground = true)
fun SecondOnBoardingScreenPreview() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        PagerScreen(onBoardingPage = OnBoardingPage.Second)
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview(showBackground = true)
fun ThirdOnBoardingScreenPreview() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        PagerScreen(onBoardingPage = OnBoardingPage.Third)
    }
}
```

**NavGraph.kt**

```
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun SetUpNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController
){
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Onboard.route
    ){
        composable(route = Screen.Onboard.route){
            OnBoardScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(route = Screen.Home.route){
            HomeScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Accompanist library for the horizontal pager with indicators. If you want to how learn to make an OnBoarding screen with indicators, you can look at this [example](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/). Also with [this link](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/main/sample/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/sample/pager/HorizontalPagerWithIndicatorSample.kt), you can look sample code.

Edit: Sample Code
https://gist.github.com/aticiadem/5b50151f540cbac5bae827f85d555ebe

Edit: Code result [For image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whVG1.png)

Comment: I have also followed the same thing, is there any mistake in the code?

Comment: Can you remove your weight codes, your code is ok but you don't see your indicator because HorizontalPager(weight = 10f) might be taking up the whole page. Give the height of all the elements to try and check if you can see the indicator.

Comment: i removed the weight code but its not working. same issue

Comment: Hi, I am sharing a code I used in the past. You can change or remove some of them according to your needs. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Ok i will try that and update you, and one more question like is there something I imported wrong that's why it's not working? Should I share my import statements?

Comment: Hello again, I didn't actually try your code. But I'll try and if I find your problem, I'll update this comment and post the problem here. By the way, I updated the code in the link. Check it again.